# WooCommerce redirect 'order received' page to ACF URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code in my functions.php to redirect my WooCommerce 'order received' page to an custom URL:

```
// Redirect WooCommerce Order Received Page to Post
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'rwl_redirectcustom');
function rwl_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://my-website.com';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now I want to redirect instead to an static URL 'https://my-website.com' to a dynamic URL which is stored in an ACF field called 'paywall_post_url' of a post.

I have tried this

```
$url = get_permalink( get_post_meta( 'paywall_post_url' ) );
```

But this didn't worked. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) requires you to pass the post ID and meta key.

you want to use the acf function [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

```
$url = get_permalink( get_field( 'paywall_post_url' ) );
```

this is if you saved the field as a post ID. otherwise it should be:

```
$url = get_field( 'paywall_post_url' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it doesn't work. I guess it's because the ACF field 'paywall_post_url' is stored in the product. And my php code is calling the order_id. I guess I must add also somehow a call for the product and the saved 'paywall_post_url' field as well??!

Comment: Yes you would need the product id served into the function - `$url = get_field( 'paywall_post_url' , $YOUR_PRODUCT_ID );`

Comment: Can you give me a complete code example? I'm a beginner and don't get the product ID well embedded :-(